# Killing an audio Clip thread

Tags: java, multithreading, javasound, audio

I am fairly new to using sounds, and I am able to play a sound, but I am having troubles with all  of the sound clip threads that java makes when I play a sound. I would like to know how I would get all sounds to run on one thread, or to die once it is done playing.

I am currently running this code to actually play a sound, creating a new instance of everything when I call the `play()` method:

```
private AudioInputStream as;
private Clip c;

public synchronized void play(final SoundType type) {
    reset();
    try {
        as = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(getSound(type));
        c = AudioSystem.getClip();
        c.open(as);
        c.start();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

What I am able to do with this, is it enables me to play multiple sounds at once, by creating a new instance of each item at once. Only problem is that it creates multiple threads in the process, and the program ends up with so many threads when playing different sounds.

Is there a more efficient method, or an approvement I could do to my current method, that would allow me to play multiple sounds at once but at the end it will kill that clip thread, or maybe have one thread that handles all sounds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write your own audio mixer. It isn't that hard. The audio data is extracted from the audio files, and the frames are summed before being output to a single SourceDataLine.

Or, you could use TinySound (code available on github). It is a nice clean implementation of exactly this sort of mixing.

One benefit of mixing to a single output: some systems (some Linux) do not support multiple outputs.

Comment: I should have mentioned a couple other alternatives: (1) use SourceDataLines instead of Clips, as they can be set up to close all the needed resources; (2) there is event listening support that will notify when a Clip or SourceDataLine completes, which can be used to close the given thread. Also, if you are only going to play a sound once, it is better to use a SourceDataLine than a Clip.